# Conection between java socket server and socket client

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to make a small example with java sockets. But i can not make it work. The server receives the petition of the client correctly. But the problem comes, when i am trying to send to the server the String "hello".

As i debugged, the InputStream in the server is null, so it doesn't print anything. I think the problem has to be in the PrinterWriter, maybe i should use another class, i tried with other classes like BufferedWriter, but i couldn't make it work

here is my code

server

```
public class ServidorFechaHora {

    static final int port = 5000;
    static String line;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            /* accept nos devuelve el Socket conectado a un nuevo cliente.
            Si no hay un nuevo cliente, se bloquea hasta que haya un
            nuevo cliente.
            */
            Socket soc = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Cliente conectado");
            // Obtenemos el flujo de entrada del socket
            InputStream is = (InputStream) soc.getInputStream();
            //Función que llevaría a cabo el envío y recepción de los datos.
            processClient(is);
        }
    }

    private static void processClient(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = bis.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);  
        }

        bis.close();
    }

}
```

client

```
public class ClienteFechaHora {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Socket client = null;
        PrintWriter output = null;
        //BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        try {
               client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
               output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), false);

               while (true) {
                   System.out.println("Enviando datos...");
                   output.write("hello");
                   output.flush();
                   Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
                   //System.out.println("Fecha y hora: " + hourdateFormat);
               }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        output.close();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just checked the server with my dummy client and is working fine

Comment: The input stream in the server is never null. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: EJP as i said i am trying to send the String "hello" from the client to the server and show it in the server method called "processClient". I think is crystal clear what im trying to do just reading the description or the code. Please, read more carefully next time instead of giving me negative points. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your server is reading from the socket line-by-line:

```
BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

while ((line = bis.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);  
}
```

[BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) is documented as follows:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

So it doesn't return until it reads a line terminator.

Your client on the other hand is just writing the string "Hello" without a line terminator:

```
output.write("hello");
output.flush();
```

If you want to read a line of text in the server, you have to send a line of text (including a line terminator) in the client:

```
output.write("hello\n");
output.flush();
```